# Where to put which OSSEC configuration - monitoring crontab

Tags: ossec

I am evaluating (vanilla) OSSEC+ (not Wazuh). If I understand the documentation correctly, all the rule-specific configuration has to be done on the server, which sounds very reasonable as I do not want to change the configuration of every single agent and a possible attacker shall not be able to manipulate it.

Following that I expect that changes in said configuration on the server are somehow reflected on the agents. But this seems not to happen in my case.

For a test I wanted to implement a crontab check. So if the crontab of the root user is changed, I want to get a notification about that.

Following the documentation I added the following to
`/var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf`
on the server:

```
<localfile>
    <log_format>full_command</log_format>
    <command>crontab -u root -l</command>
    <frequency>30</frequency>
</localfile>
```

and the following to `/var/ossec/rules/local_rules.xml` (on the server as well)

```
<rule id="500002" level="7">
    <if_sid>530</if_sid>
    <match>ossec: output: 'crontab</match>
    <check_diff />
    <description>Crontab for user has changed!.</description>
 </rule>
```

After that I restarted the server and the agent.

Now because the server is monitoring itself as well I can verify that this configuration is working in principle, because I do get the desired notification if I change the crontab on the server.

But this does not happen for the agent.
Following other questions/answers on stackoverflow I tried adding

```
logcollector.remote_commands=1
```

to `/var/ossec/etc/local_internal_options.conf` (on the agent)

and restarted the agent multiple times.

I can see that the agent is doing something when I look into
`/var/ossec/logs/ossec.log` (agent)
and I do see it executing some other commands, but not the one I configured.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to add every configuration to the server and every single agent, despite the documentation telling me otherwise?

PS. It does work if I add the command-configuration into `/var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf` on the agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to provide configuration to agents from the manager you must use [Centralized agent configuration](https://www.ossec.net/docs/docs/manual/agent/agent-configuration.html), you may append configuration to groups of agents by adding them to the `agent.conf` of each group.

Unless specified otherwise all agents will originally be part of the `default` group, so you must add this to `/var/ossec/etc/shared/default/agent.conf` on the manager so the agent will use it.

When adding configuration to the manager's `/var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf` this will only affect the manager's operations.